# Is it dangerous not closing Cursor in getCursor method?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I've made my own `getCursor` method which looks like this

```
protected Cursor getCursor(String selectQuery) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

Since I cannot call `cursor.close()` before I return it, is it dangerous leaving cursor open like this? Or it will close as soon as the method returns its object?

Answer (score 1):

You will get at some some point a "TooManyCursorsException" - or [something like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455738/android-too-many-open-files-error). Where you're using the cursor you could have a try {} finally{} block and in finally you could say:

```
if(cursor != null) {
   cursor.close();
}
```

I am used from web programming to create model pojos when reading data from DAO and use that in up-levels. I am never sending the Cursor to above layers.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible not to retun Cursor in Android since it hold the whole structure returned by a query

Comment: Where is that stated? Nobody prevents you from building custom DAO pojos and forward a collection of those to who's interested. By that time you've closed the cursor. From my point of view it's an anti-pattern to send the cursor from DAO layer to upper levels.

Answer (score 1):

If you need your cursor with activity life cycle, use call `Activity.startManagingCursor(Cursor c)`, otherwise you should close your cursor explicitly.

Comment: From doc: `This method was deprecated in API level 11. Use the new CursorLoader class with LoaderManager instead; this is also available on older platforms through the Android compatibility package.`

Comment: @WarrenFaith Right, use cursor loader is a better way. But sometime, even though using cusorload, the cursor would not be closed.

Comment: Than you are doing it wrong or there is a bug in the implementation of the CursorLoader. I never had to close a cursor since I am using CursorLoader.

Comment: @WarrenFaith I do not know the reason, i remember it has appeared in some devices, not all.